# Lib or example code to handle bitmap in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have small test to handle bitmap in MFC (VC++ 2008).

I want to process left mouse click or right mouse click on a image to call any event.

(I dont want to calculate coordinates, I only want to handle image as a object and left click, right click on that object)

Anyone know the MFC lib or source code, please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a picture control to display the image.  The picture control is represented in MFC by CStatic. Since CStatic does not generate the mouse notifications that you want you need to customize it, using the MFC subclassing technique.

First you create a control member variable of type CStatic. Then to add the custom mouse handling that you want you create a class derived from CStatic and add message handlers for all the mouse messages that you are interested in, like WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_RBUTTONDOWN. Change your control member variable to be your CStatic-derived class instead of CStatic. Now you are intercepting the mouse messages that come in to the picture control.  Write a little code in each message handler to notify the parent dialog/form, like...

```
#define UWM_LIMAGECLICK (WM_USER+10) // your custom message

GetParent()->PostMessage(UWM_IMAGECLICK, IDC_IMAGE, 0); // your picture control's ID
```

The parent window can receive and handle this message with

```
ON_MESSAGE(UWM_LIMAGECLICK, OnLImageClick) // in the message map

LRESULT CYourParentClass::OnLImageClick(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ....the image was L clicked
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample project for it? thanks

Comment: Search the net for "MFC subclassing"